# 404 not found "requested URL was not found"

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I'm trying to make a button in sida2 take me to resultat and post the information named MJ from the input form but I get an error 404 The requested URL was not found on the server and I don't understand why. This is the html part:

```
<form action="/sida2/resultat.html" method="POST">
<input title="" placeholder="MJ/kq foder" type="text" name="MJ" required>
<br>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And this is the python part:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return(render_template("hemsida.html")) 


@app.route('/sida2/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def sida2():
    return(render_template("andrasidan.html"))


@app.route('/sida2/resultat', methods=['POST'])
def resultat():    
    if request.method=='POST':       
        mj= request.form["MJ"]



    return(render_template("resultat.html"))

if __name__ =="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I assume it's something obvious I'm missing but I just can't seem to find it.

Comment: Looks like your form `action` should hit the `/sida1/resultat` endpoint, not the `.html` file.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#flask.url_for) to generate URLs to Flask views. The view you want is `resultat`.

```
<form action="{{ url_for('resultat') }}" method="POST">
```

This will generate the appropriate URL for your `resultat()` function:

```
@app.route('/sida2/resultat', methods=['POST'])
def resultat():
```

The URL you currently have in your form action (`/sida2/resultat.html`) will not work as your code binds to the URL `/sida2/resultat` instead.

For a quick overview of the benefits of why you should use `url_for` over hardcoding your URLs, check out [the Flask quickstart section on the topic](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/quickstart/#url-building).